# PHPUnit - is this the correct way

Tags: yii, phpunit

I am staring out with PHPUnit today. As i use Yii framework i am using the built in functions.

Can someone let me know if i am proceeding correctly

Here is the model function

```
public function getTaxRate()
{
    if($this->province_id != 13 && $this->province_id != 14)
    {
        return 21;
    }
    elseif($this->identification[0] == 'B')
    {
        return 0;       
    }
    else
    {
        return 7;       
    }

}
```

Here is the test case

```
public function testgetTaxRate()
{
    $accountData = array(
                                array('identification'=>'x2', 'province_id'=>'50', 'result'=>21), // test for 21
                                array('identification'=>'x2', 'province_id'=>'13', 'result'=>7), // test for 7
                                array('identification'=>'B2', 'province_id'=>'13', 'result'=>0), // test for 0
                        );
    foreach($accountData as $account)
    {
        $acc = new Accounts();
        $acc->identification=$account['identification'];
        $acc->province_id=$account['province_id'];
        $tax = $acc->getTaxRate();
        $this->assertEquals($tax, $account['result']);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly, The result is correct and it errors when I expect it to.

Regards

Comment: can u post the error here

Comment: Hiya, when i said it errors, i meant that if i break the method the test fails as it was supposed to sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good rule for organizing tests: one test per one case. If you have only one logic, you should use data provider mechanism (provided by `PHPUnit`) for this purpose in order to avoid code duplication.

Docs: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

And an example for you:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider dataProvider_getTaxRate
 */
public function testGetTaxRate($id, $provinceId, $expectedResult)
{
    $acc = new Accounts();
    $acc->identification = $id;
    $acc->province_id = $provinceId;

    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $acc->getTaxRate());
}

public static function dataProvider_getTaxRate()
{
    return array(
        array('x2', '50', 21),
        array('x2', '13', 7),
        array('x2', '14', 7),
        array('B2', '13', 0),
    );
}
```

One more thing - it's good habit that expectations should be at first argument in assertions.

Comment: Many thanks, this is how I have now written my next few tests.